# How to implement push notification in Qt android application

Tags: qt, push-notification, notifications, qtandroidextras, android-push-notification

I develop a android application using Qt, now i wanna send push notifications.
i couldn't find any push notification service that has a Qt SDK. i should mention that because of sanctions i couldn't use Firebase. is it possible to use other SDK using QAndroidJniObject in Qt? is there any other solutions in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

There is very good Qt example about notification and it using [QAndroidJniObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html).

```
void NotificationClient::updateAndroidNotification()
{
    QAndroidJniObject javaNotification = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(m_notification);
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org/qtproject/example/notification/NotificationClient",
                                       "notify",
                                       "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                       javaNotification.object<jstring>());
}
```

This example demonstrates how to add a custom Java class to an Android application, and how to call into this using the JNI convenience APIs in the Qt Android Extras module.

Qt android notification example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html

It's in QtCreator examples since Qt 5.7 and later.

Comment: @Elsiete.moon If my answer was helpful could you accept it, thanks.

Comment: the Qt example was very helpful and i really appreciate it, but the example is about creating local notification and that's actually the reason i didn't accept your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `local notification ` ?

Comment: Ok, let me explain in another way, i want to send notifications to users even if my app is closed, i can do this with services like [onesignal](https://onesignal.com/) and [pushy](https://pushy.me/) but they didn't support Qt.